# General question: Adding new test code to embedded system

Tags: testing, embedded, real-time

this maybe will be off topic, but I am preparing for an exam in real time. And I have been browsing the book and Internet for an answer for a problem.

Basically I wonder if by adding additional test code if it may change the real time behavior for an embedded system, and or also if it will introduce new errors.

Anyone who might know the answer for this, or refer me to some reading material for it?

Comment: What do you mean by 'test code'.. Code to verify the functionality of the system itself? Kinda what ASSERTS do? Or just debug outputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is too general.. So I guess the default answer would be it depends.. But considering the possibilities as an exercise of logic and thought, yes it surely can!

There are many schemes available to guarantee the 'real-timeness' of an embedded system. For example, one can have a pre-emptive timer based ISR to service the real-time task.. In such a case, your test code could possibly not affect the 'real-timeness'.. But if the testing takes too long, and the context switches are not pre-emptive, you could get into trouble..

But again it depends on what you're testing and how you're testing. Your test code can possible mess with the timers, interrupts or the memory of system. The possibilities to mess up stuff if you're not careful are endless..

Having an OS underneath will prevent some errors, but again depending on how it works, you may be saved from bad 'test code'..

Comment: I am kinda trying to read in. From by own point right now. I think the testing is about ASSERTS and similar. Therefore I can't see the reason why it would mess up with the real time behavior. Since the additional test code is only used for ASSERTS. But I might have wrong since I remembered from a lecture that the professor said that it will affect the real time behavior

Comment: Hmm.. Practically speaking, most modern IDEs (compilers) will compile out the Assert code when you try to compile the code for 'deployment'.. But again, we should stick to the logical exercise.. I have definitely encountered cases, which are very 'Hisenberg-esque'.. The act of debugging or 'watching' the code itself causes an error.. And these are the cases of test code actually messing up functionality..

Comment: With real time systems, if the timing is not controlled by some kind of independent timer but by the amount of time taken to execute a certain amount of code (baaad design, but it does exist), adding code (even though it's asserts or debugs) can definitely screw up the timing and hence the real-time guarantees of the system.. I have seen this happening with debug code which sent things to the a serial port.. The serial driver was taking so long that the 'quick debug' wasn't really that quick and messed up the timing for the real-time baseband os..

Comment: what does the `Hisenberg-esque` tried to google it found in wikipedia, but it is refered as the `uncertainty principle`. Anyway can I say that adding new code it will have the same effect as if I am changing the scheduler, e.g. if I have a cyclic schedule and I am adding a new task?

Comment: Yup. I meant to say it like an analogy of the uncertainly principle applied to programming.. "The act of observing the code itself changes the working of the code".. About the scheduler, yes that could be a way to look at it. But again depends on what scheme was used to guarantee the 'realtime-ness'.. And you could also screw up the 'realtime-ness' by increasing the time taken for one of the tasks instead of needing to add another task..

Comment: Aha, I kinda get this somewhat now. Just one more thing I need some clarification. Why is it needed to get debug output? Or is it only needed during the production phase, and is then removed when released?

Comment: Generally that's how it should be done.. But, sometimes it might be needed for some kind of statistical testing in production rounds, or if it's needed to analyze errors and failures in production etc..

Answer (score 1):

Yes, when you add code (test, diagnostic, statistic) it may change the real time behavior. It depends on the design, the implementation and the CPU power if it will actually change the behavior. You also have more lines of code and the probability for errors may increase. But I wouldn't say, "it will introduce errors", since it *can* introduce errors.

Comment: How would the additional lines of code lead to change to the behavior? I'm guessing that the code is compiled into byte code before it is installed into the embedded system.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can.  See [How can adding data to a segment in flash memory screw up a program's timing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/129911/10396) for an example of how even adding non-executable code can adjust timing enough to screw up a system.

Answer (score 0):

Yea, changing your code base could totally change its timing. Consider if you dumped some debug output to a serial port, it takes time to call that function, format the data, and if the function is synchronous, then for it to wait for data to go out. This kinda stuff definitely changes system timing behavior.